# Почему cookie не устанавливаются перед редиректом?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Подскажите пожалуйста почему cookie не устанавливаются перед редиректом?

Сам редирект работает, но куки не устанавливаются.

Но а если убрать редирект, то куки устанавливаются.

Код на CodeIgniter 4

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        helper('cookie');
        set_cookie('hash', 123, 60*60*24*30*12);
        return redirect()->route('user');
    }
}
```

Comment: Проверьте не выводиться ли ничего в браузер перед установкой значения в куки. Они должны быть проинициализированы до того как что-то будет выведено в браузер.

Comment: `set_cookie('hash', 123, 60*60*24*30*12, '/');`

Comment: @Максим Степанов, неа, тоже не работает, без редиректа сама установка кук работает

Comment: @Вадим Александру, нет, на выводе ничего нет

Comment: А как вы проверяли есть или нет? Куки кидаютья в хедер, посмотрите какие заголовки кидает сервер.

Comment: @SergeyMironov я поэтому и дописал путь, чтобы кука на весь домен ставилась.

Comment: @Вадим Александру, сам метод index у меня только для установки куки и редиректа, вывода на страницу никакого не должно быть. А как правильно сделать такой функционал?

Comment: @Максим Степанов, 4 параметр это адрес домена, можно его не указывать, 5 тоже можно не указывать (он для всего сайта). https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

Нашел такое решение, других вариантов похоже нет

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        helper(['url', 'cookie']);
        set_cookie('hash', 123, 60*60*24*30*12);
        return "<meta http-equiv='REFRESH' content='0;url=". base_url() ."'><body><a href='". base_url() ."'>Continue...</a></body>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Там вроде какой-то подвох был, попробуйте так:

```
return redirect()->route('user')->setCookie('hash', 123, 60*60*24*30*12)->send();
```

или так

```
set_cookie('hash', 123, 60*60*24*30*12);
return redirect()->route('user')->withCookies();
```